# numpy: raising a matrix to a power produces strange result

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

My solution to the [KnightDialer problem on Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/knight-dialer):

```
import numpy as np
class Solution:
  def knightDialer(self, N: int) -> int:
    M = np.matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
    return np.sum(M**(N-1)) % (10**9 + 7)
```

It works correctly for values of N up to 51. E.g. for N = 1 it correctly returns 10, for N = 2 it correctly returns 20, for N = 3 it correctly returns 46 and so on. Than at N > 51 it stops producing an accurate result (for N = 52 it returns 107679695 instead of 
690023703). I am not sure why but somehow raising the matrix to a power > 51 leads to an inaccurate result.

I tried replacing `M**(N-1)` with `np.linalg.matrix_power(M, (N-1))` but the output is still not accurate. My hunch is that there is some numpy "magic" going behind the scenes but I am not sure what is it.

Comment: @harold Not sure I understand. Can I at all raise a matrix to a power greater than 51? I thought that this should be possible. I was able to solve accurately this problem by using an alternative way of computation (no matrices) but I am surprised that numpy would struggle with it. After all, matrix exponentiation is recommended as a generic solution to this problem (number of walks between vertices of an undirected graph): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890620/finding-path-lengths-by-the-power-of-adjacency-matrix-of-an-undirected-graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy struggles because it works with fixed-size integers such as `int32` or `int64` (which one is used here depends on your python installation). Exponentiating the matrix like this quickly makes the entries larger than the limit of that data type, resulting in truncation.

With regular Python integers, it is possible to use this kind of implementation (multiply the matrix first and apply the modular reduction afterwards), because regular Python integers can have much higher values. For example:

```
def mm(A, B):
    return [[sum([x*y for (x, y) in zip(row, col)]) for col in zip(*B)] for row in A]

def knightDialer(N: int) -> int:
    M = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    N = N - 1
    res = [[int(i == j) for j in range(len(M))] for i in range(len(M))]
    while N:
        if N & 1: res = mm(res, M)
        M = mm(M, M)
        N >>= 1
    print(M)
    return sum([sum(i) for i in zip(*res)]) % (10**9 + 7)
```

Applying the modular reduction during the exponentiation lets numpy matrixes work without running out of bits:

```
def knightDialer(N: int) -> int:
    M = np.matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=np.int64)
    N = N - 1
    res = np.eye(M.shape[0], dtype=np.int64)
    while N:
        if N & 1: res = res * M % (10**9 + 7)
        M = M * M % (10**9 + 7)
        N >>= 1
    return np.sum(res) % (10**9 + 7)
```

Using `dtype=np.int64` is necessary in case for your installation the default integer type is `int32`. `int32` is big enough to hold numbers below `10**9 + 7`, but during the matrix multiplication there will be products between two such numbers (and then they are summed, too) and at that time overflow can occur if `int32` was used.

Comment: Thanks! I tested both solutions and the numpy one seems to be almost 5 times faster using the tests on Leetcode (108ms vs 484ms) while taking more memory (29.2MB vs 13.9MB). In all cases, having both solutions is very informative - thanks again for the detailed explanations.